# Getting errors when using variables with sed, but getting desired result on command line

Tags: bash, sed

I have in my bash script a line of code:

```
url=$(echo "$url" | sed -r 's@{$regex}@\2\3.v1\4@')
```

where:

- `url = "  - https://ci-files.gr4bb.com/templates/v2/kubeval.src.yml"`
- `regex = ^(.*)(https://ci-files\.gr4bb\.com/)templates/v2/(.+)(\.ya?ml)$`

This line will fail with error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

The char 21 position would correspond to the letter 'e' in the regex.

However, if I run this on the command line:

```
echo "  - https://ci-files.gr4bb.com/templates/v2/kubeval.src.yml" | sed -r 's@^(.*)(https://ci-files.gr4bb.com/)templates/v2/(.+)(\.ya?ml)$@\2\3.v1\4@'
```

I get the desired result, which is:

```
https://ci-files.gr4bb.com/kubeval.src.v1.yml
```

If I replace the single quotes with double quotes in the expression:

```
url=$(echo "$url" | sed -r "s@{$regex}@\2\3.v1\4@")
```

I get a different error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: invalid reference \4 on `s' command's RHS
```

Can someone please explain what is going on exactly?

Comment: Read the question to the end, please. I use double quotes later and get a different error. If I'm misunderstanding, I'd appreciate some example code. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @anubhava Getting the same error ```sed: -e expression #1, char 32: invalid reference \4 on `s' command's RHS```

Comment: `sed -r "s@$regex@\\2\\3.v1\\4@" <<< "$url"` works pretty well for me.

Comment: Apologies for the question. It was a bug on my part, I kept sending an empty string to sed input. @anubhava Thanks for taking the time to read and answer, and sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to match actual braces, `{$regex}` should be `${regex}` or just `$regex`.

Parameter expansion doesn't happen inside single-quotes (`'`).

Try:

```
echo "$url" | sed -r 's@'"$regex"'@\2\3.v1\4@'
```

or (backslash is not special when followed by a digit):

```
echo "$url" | sed -r "s@$regex@\2\3.v1\4@"
```